# I want to plot the MKmapannotation by the photos

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is my code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

    MapLocation *Annotation = annotation;

    static NSString *identifier = @"MapLocation";

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapLocation class]]) {

    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationViewBus = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationViewTaxi = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationViewSam = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationViewMetro = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    //bus
    if (!annotationViewBus ) {
        annotationViewBus = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        annotationViewBus.enabled = YES;
        annotationViewBus.canShowCallout = YES;

        if (busStatus==YES) {
            annotationViewBus.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"annotationBus.png"];//here we use a nice image instead of the default pins
        return annotationViewBus;

        }else {
        annotationViewBus.annotation = annotation;

        }

    }


    //taxi
    if (!annotationViewTaxi ) {
        annotationViewTaxi = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        annotationViewTaxi.enabled = YES;
        annotationViewTaxi.canShowCallout = YES;

        if (taxiStatus==YES) {
            annotationViewTaxi.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"annotationTaxi.png"];//here we use a nice image instead of the default pins
          //  return annotationViewTaxi;

        }else {
        annotationViewTaxi.annotation = annotation;
        }

    }


    //sam
    if (!annotationViewSam ) {
            annotationViewSam = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
            annotationViewSam.enabled = YES;
            annotationViewSam.canShowCallout = YES;

            if(samStatus==YES){
                annotationViewSam.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"annotationSam.png"];
                UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
                [rightButton setTitle:[Annotation name] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(chatButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //display another view
                annotationViewSam.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
               // return annotationViewSam;

            }else {
                annotationViewSam.annotation = annotation;
            }

        }


    //metro
    if (!annotationViewMetro ) {
                annotationViewMetro = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
                annotationViewMetro.enabled = YES;
                annotationViewMetro.canShowCallout = YES;

                if(metroStatus==YES){
                    annotationViewMetro.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"annotationMetro.png"];

                }else {
                    annotationViewMetro.annotation = annotation;
                }
        //return annotationViewMetro;


        }


}
return nil;
```

}

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what the exact problem or errors are and what your actual question is.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten return (MKAnnotationView *) for each Annotation View type.
Just add return AnnotationView for each type. For example:

//metro

```
if (!annotationViewMetro ) {
            annotationViewMetro = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
            annotationViewMetro.enabled = YES;
            annotationViewMetro.canShowCallout = YES;

            if(metroStatus==YES){
                annotationViewMetro.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"annotationMetro.png"];

            }else {
                annotationViewMetro.annotation = annotation;
            }
```

just uncomment this line:

```
    return annotationViewMetro;

    }
```